# CSS Static Progress Bar filled by multiple values

Tags: css, progress-bar

I have this fixed progress bar that takes as `width` its size and back some value, let's say `val1=30%`. I would like to add a second value let's say `val2=70%` in the same bar, so that it will fill the remaining space but with a different color, so that the progress bar will show both.

Generalizing this, the same should work having more than two values, like with three values here: `val1=0.3`, `val2=0.3` and `val3=0.4`, etc.

I would like to achieve this only using by CSS, no additional Javascript, since I have all the values fulfilled already in the page and I'm using templates so I can iterate over these values.

```css
.miniBarProgress {
    background-color: #8a898a;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0rem;
}
.miniBar {
    height: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #8a898a;
    position: relative;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 2rem);
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniBar"><div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 30%;"></div></div>
```

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks to the answer below I have fixed up the code to make it working.

```css
.miniBarProgress {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0rem;
}
.miniBar {
    height: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #8a898a;
    position: relative;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 2rem);
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniBar">
<div class="miniBarProgress" style="left: 0; width: 30%; background-color: gray;"></div>
<div class="miniBarProgress" style="left: 30%; width: 40%; background-color: red;"></div>
<div class="miniBarProgress" style="left: 70%; width: 30%; background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need another `miniBarProgress` for each value. Use the `left` property to start from where the previous value ended (i.e. `left` + `width`). Here is an example with 3 values:

```css
.miniBarProgress1 {
  background-color: #8a898a;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0rem;
  width: 20%;
}

.miniBarProgress2 {
  background-color: #ff0;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
}

.miniBarProgress3 {
  background-color: #0ff;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 60%;
  width: 30%;
}

.miniBar {
  height: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #8a898a;
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="miniBar">
  <div class="miniBarProgress1"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress2"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress3"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use the same class `miniBarProgress` for all bars and always start from zero. In this case, you'll have to order the bars in reverse (longer to shorter) or use the `z-index` property to do that. Each bar will hide part of the bars behind it:

```css
.miniBarProgress {
  background-color: #8a898a;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0rem;
}

.miniBar {
  height: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #8a898a;
  position: relative;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 2rem);
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Reverse order:</p>
<div class="miniBar">
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 90%; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 60%; background-color: #ff0;"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 20%; background-color: #8a898a;"></div>
</div>
<p>Using z-index</p>
<div class="miniBar">
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 20%; z-index: 3; background-color: #8a898a;"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 60%; z-index: 2; background-color: #ff0;"></div>
  <div class="miniBarProgress" style="width: 90%; z-index: 1; background-color: #0ff;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This will work for two values. Sorry I have specified multiple values in the title, but not in the comment. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I've added 2 other solutions. Select the one that you like the most.